# Processing a Large CSV String from calling Web service API

Tags: java, rest

I call a rest service which returns an ID of an object in the first call. It gives me the length in bytes in addition to the ID of the object to read.

However, the CSV data returned could be up to 200,000 lines long. This causes an out of memory exception due to reading all 200,000 thousand lines from a rest call into memory in a Java program.

The `Map` returned is a CSV structure that the spring template returns. The problem is that when the equivalent CSV file is over 200,000 lines, the `LinkedList` can't hold it, so I get an out of memory exception.

**Is there any other way to manipulate the `RestTemplate` API to process the data as a `Stream` that can be read gradually?**

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance();

builder.scheme("https).pathSegment("/file-object").host(hostName);

// Call the third-party Rest API
ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = 

    restTemplate.exchange(
        builder.queryParam("fileId", "fjr666eH").build().toUri(), 
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new HttpEntity(httpAuthorizationHeaders("UID","XFCode:66w000")),
        Object.class
    );

// CSV file is returned by Spring as a linked list. But since data is 
// large I get an OOM exception

LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = 

    (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) responseEntity.getBody();
```

Comment: suggest you search for `java how to stream json`

Comment: As you did not provide any code , i guess best option would be use workbook. As for the REST service , you can make that yourself whatever you like.http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html

Comment: I found this do not know if that helps https://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily/

Comment: Excuse me? "Help fast!!"? At your reputation, you should know better than to be so demanding by now.

Comment: Sorry, not meaning to sound demanding. I've been under time pressure and was just trying to sound urgent.

Comment: The result is CSV not JSON

Comment: Also please bear in mind it's a third-party Rest API  I have no control over otherwise otherwise it wouldn't be an issue

Comment: Please read: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: That being said, though, the edit does improve the question a lot, so I retracted my downvote and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use a Streaming feature provided by Spring Rest API. I used the SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory, BufferedReader and was able to set the chunk size to read at a time.